# Saving array into the file (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, io, printwriter

I need to solve such task:

1. Randomly generate the length of the array - **save this int into file ("input.txt)" as a first digit**;
2. Randomly generate array elements - **save each element into the file ("input.txt")**

But the array elements won't save into file.

As I can see from console array has got digits, but they don't save into file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Main().run();

    }

    Random rand;
    Scanner sc;
    PrintWriter pr, pr2;

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
    pr2 = new PrintWriter(new File("input.txt"));
    pr = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    rand = new Random();

    int a = rand.nextInt((int) Math.pow(10, 3));
    System.out.println(a);
    pr2.print(a);
    pr2.close();
    sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    int[] arr = new int[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt((int) Math.pow(10, 3));

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + i + ": " + arr[i]);
        pr2.print(arr[i]);

    }

    pr2.close();
    return;
    }

}
```

Comment: You close pr2 and then try to write to it. Get rid of the statement before sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")), that closes the writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the stream with `pr2.close();` and then trying to print something through it. Then you close it again. Remove the first `pr2.close();` And it should all work.
Also you're having unnecessary Scanner object and second PrintWriter.

Comment: Add a new line symbol too: pr2.println(a);

Comment: Thank you. Scanner and second printwriter I need for further actions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling `pr2.close()` right after you write the length of the array.  Once you close the `PrintWriter`, it will no longer allow anything to be written to the file; thus, when you later try to write the values in the array to `pr2`, `pr2` says, "gosh, I know this guy wants me to write something but I'm closed, I just can't do it!" and so nothing gets written.

The `PrintWriter` works by storing all of your `write(...)` and `print(...)` calls into memory, and then actually writing them into your text file when you call the `close()` or `flush()` method. Although it's not necessary, if you wanted functional similarity to your current use of the first `close()` call, you could use `flush()` instead, but make sure that you do call `close()` when you are completely done using the `Scanner` (otherwise you're just asking for a memory leak).